# EJB-CMT JPA flush transaction

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, ejb

I am writing an EJB-CMT bean using JPA. In my EJB method, I have some persist actions and I need call 'flush' after one of 'persist' action.

Here are my sample code:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MyEjb {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPU")
    EntityManager em;

    public void addSome() {
        User u = //;
        em.persist(u);

        em.flush(); // ----------- CALL FLUSH HERE

        UserGroup g1;
        em.persist(g1); // --- Add another

        UserGroup g2;
        em.persist(g2); // -- Add another
    }
}
```

**My question is**:  Can I get all codes in 'addSome' method executed in ONE transaction? I know that if I don't use 'flush', all codes executed in one transaction.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

sure, you can annotate your method with [@TransactionAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttribute.html) with `value=REQUIRES_NEW` and your method will get executed in a single isolated transaction and your entity manager will get flushed when you return from the method, check more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html)